# Fallback disables - Hystrix

Tags: fallback, hystrix, circuit-breaker

I'm using Hystrix in my environment associated with Liferay and other external services. My circuit gets some fails and opens the circuit to a specific service. Everything is fine so far. However, the circuit never changes to closed again. My fallback is disabled with this property:

hystrix.command.default.fallback.enabled=false

What should I do to circuit checks that my service is working and change to closed again? I have verified the circuits with the Hystrix Dashboard.

```
com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: BusinessActivity-FlightAvailabilityV1 timed-out and fallback disabled.
at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.getFallbackOrThrowException(AbstractCommand.java:843) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.access$200(AbstractCommand.java:59) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$9.call(AbstractCommand.java:600) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$9.call(AbstractCommand.java:580) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:139) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar!/:1.1.5]
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar!/:1.1.5]
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar!/:1.1.5]
at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$1.run(AbstractCommand.java:953) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:41) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:37) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable.run(HystrixContextRunnable.java:57) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$2.tick(AbstractCommand.java:970) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
at com.netflix.hystrix.util.HystrixTimer$1.run(HystrixTimer.java:99) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    ... 18 common frames omitted

2017-05-11 17:11:14.979  WARN 97456 --- [io-8080-exec-14] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering

com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: BusinessActivity-FlightAvailabilityV1 short-circuited and fallback disabled.
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.getFallbackOrThrowException(AbstractCommand.java:843) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.access$200(AbstractCommand.java:59) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$1.call(AbstractCommand.java:421) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$1.call(AbstractCommand.java:369) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar!/:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar!/:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar!/:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar!/:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar!/:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar!/:1.1.5]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8460) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar!/:1.1.5]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$ObservableCommand$1.call(AbstractCommand.java:1133) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$ObservableCommand$1.call(AbstractCommand.java:1129) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar!/:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar!/:1.1.5]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8553) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar!/:1.1.5]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8520) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar!/:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.BlockingOperatorToFuture.toFuture(BlockingOperatorToFuture.java:57) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar!/:1.1.5]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.toFuture(BlockingObservable.java:401) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar!/:1.1.5]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.queue(HystrixCommand.java:378) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:334) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
    at br.com.smiles.hystrix.routes.SmilesHostRoutingFilter.run(SmilesHostRoutingFilter.java:196) ~[smiles-hystrix-server.jar!/:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:197) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:161) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:120) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:158) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequestInternal(ZuulController.java:43) [spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:261) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:115) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Hystrix circuit short-circuited and is OPEN
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$1.call(AbstractCommand.java:418) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
    ... 85 common frames omitted
```

Here are my hystrix properties:

```
# POOL SIZES
hystrix.threadpool.default.coreSize=70

#QUEUES
hystrix.threadpool.checkout.queueSizeRejectionThreshold=5


#TIMEOUTS
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=30000
hystrix.command.getMember.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=10000
hystrix.command.checkout.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=10000
hystrix.command.joinClub.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=10000
hystrix.command.getAvailability.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=10000
hystrix.command.myFlights.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=10000
hystrix.command.login.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=10000

#general HTTP TIMEOUT
zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis=70000
zuul.host.maxTotalConnections=600

#hystrix.command.checkout.circuitBreaker.forceOpen=true
hystrix.threadpool.default.metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds=10000
hystrix.command.default.circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold=7

# FALLBACKS
hystrix.command.default.fallback.enabled=false

metrics.healthSnapshot.intervalInMilliseconds=500
```

Comment: can you put your hystrix configuration

Comment: @pvpkiran I just updated my question with some properties.

Comment: by default circuit should be open after 5 seconds. because the default value for this property `hystrix.command.default.circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds` is 5000 ms according to doc(https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds) . Try setting it manually for say 10 seconds and see if the circuit opens after 10 seconds

Comment: thank you! it works like a charm :)

Comment: good to know. cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know circuit is opened, all requests during `sleepWindowInMillisec‌​onds (default 5000ms)` will be rejected. After `sleepWindowInMillisec‌` time, your circuit becomes half-opened state and it allows just SINGLE request to flow to your backend server. If it fails, your circuit will become opened again and all following requests will be rejected during next `sleepWindowInMillisec‌` time. If the request that was arrived at half-opened state succeeds, your circuit will become closed state.

If your circuit looks opened always, it means that the request at half-opened state failed again. You can check the situation with exception message.

Answer (score 0):

The result of my test is that:

**if hystrix.command.default.fallback.enabled = true**, the circuit breaker can turn off after a specified time, otherwise, it cannot be closed normally